# <label><label/> tag inside <A><A/> tag with javascript function on the href fails to run

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, text-to-speech

I have a `<label><label/>` tag inside `<A><A/>` tag, the `<A>` tag has a `href` that calls a JavaScript function.

The JavaScript fails to call when run under IE, but works a treat on all the others I need it too.

I know this is probably not normal, but I'm looking for a speech reader quick fix to a really old project, so lets not get into the why's and why not's. :)

I've searched and can find no reference as to why this does not work, heres my test code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Label and Links Test For Speech Readers</title>
</head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onHello()
    {
        alert("hello");
    }    
</script>

<body>
    <p><b>Label and Links Test For Speech Readers</b></p>
    <p>This is a test a patch to an historic application, Tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE & BlackBerry OS-6(similator)</p>
    <p>
        # TEST 1<br />
        <a href="javascript:onHello();">Hello1</a>
        <br />Current basic link style, that doesn't work with speech readers
    </p>
    <p>
        # TEST 2<br />
        <a href="javascript:onHello();"><label style="cursor:pointer">Hello2</label></a>
        <br />Easy fix, but this does not work for IE
    </p>
    <p>
        # TEST 3<br />
        <label onclick="javascript:onHello();" style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">Hello3</label>
        <br />More work to fix, but compatible with all noted broswers
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put Javascript in the `href`, that is disabled in some browsers under some circumstances, for security reasons.

Use the `onclick` event to run code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="onHello();return false;"><label style="cursor:pointer">Hello2</label></a>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of when javascript is disabled in href for security reasons?

Comment: I don't know if it's ever disabled by default (for security or any other reasons) but I do know "javascript:" is not a proper protocol so, imho, should never be on the href property.

Comment: @Guffa - That was kind of the impression I got, I know IE have become far more strict in there syntax. Works a treat!

Comment: leave out the `href` tag if you don't want the website to bounce each time the onclick is executed

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a pure syntax issue.
Label is meant to be used with form and can be clicked by users to interact with form inputs.

I understand you said no "why" and "why not" but use a label inside a link is definitely not a good idea ... that's not just a tag inside a tag since label tag is supposed to be clicked so you have 2 tags which can be clicked. IE seems to give more importance to label in your example, so it does not run you code in the link.

Comment: I see what you mean, make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You should run the javascript on the onClick event, don't place it on the href (use a # or something as href).

Also, if you want to prevent the link from being followed don't forget to return false; (or event.preventDefault()). E.g.

```
       <a href="#" onClick="onHello(); return false;">Hello1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead using in href use in onclick

```
<a href='#' onclick="onHello(); return false;">Hello1</a>
```

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" in the onclick attribute as onclick is an event automatically captured by javascript. You also need to add `return false;` to the end. Otherwise the page will reload because this is an anchor tag. `<a href='#' onclick="onHello(); return false;">Hello1</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you skip the a-tag at all, bind the javascript snippet on the label?

```
<label style="cursor:pointer" onclick="onHello();">Hello2</label>
```

Comment: I have around 200+ files to change, I want to try and script an automated fix for the vast majority and then deal with the edge cases. For this project it just not worth putting time into a end-of-life project. But I do agree with you, its the solution I would have choosen otherwise.